# Add invoker to already deployed OpenWhisk

Tags: openwhisk

I've an OpenWhisk instance running on my Ubuntu server.

How can I deploy a new invoker on another machine which will function as an invoker of the current system?

Answer (score 1):

This is as simple as running another Invoker instance with a unique ID. Invokers register automatically with the controller via Kafka, the `health` topic. This is the Docker's `cmd` instruction you could use:

`` "cmd": "/bin/sh -c \"/invoker/bin/invoker `hostname | tr -dc '0-9'` >> /dev/stderr\"" ``

Comment: What is the `health` topic? And I should take the docker image from my original deployed OW and run it in my other machine with the original machine IP as the first parameter to /invoker/bin/invoker?